# Add a specific Domain to Multiple Feature CLasses at once (batch)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arccatalog, domains

I have a domain named "Life Cycle" with coded- "active" or "inactive". I need to apply this domain to over 150+ Feature Classes (in a SDE if that matters) via ArcCatalog. I know how to do this manually by adding the domain to each feature class field; but it will take all a very long time to do this for 150+ Feature Classes and I know I will have more domains similar to this that I will have to add eventually to these Feature CLasses down the road.

I want to know if there is a tool/add-in or script someone can enlighten me on automating this process. Or allow me to add the domain to the specific Field "Life Cycle" for all desired Feature Classes at once.

Comment: If you need help with a script then please post a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I haven't created a script I would have no idea where to start to attempt to automate this process. I was wondering if there was a tool that could add domains in a batch rather one at a time.

Comment: Without using ArcPy you will be reliant on what you can do with the Batch Grid or ModelBuilder iteration.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. I am not very good with Python or (ArcPy) so I will stick with the model until i strengthen my python skills. much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a model to iterate over your feature classes in ArcSDE, add the Apply Domain tool, set your parameters, then press play.

Comment: Yah this works but still open for a better solution. I still have to copy+paste the tool for each feature class I want to add the domain to. (because of the unique outputs) but still a lot faster than manually selecting the feature class properties and doing it manually.